# Power BI - "The key didn't match any rows in the table" - Appended PBI dataflow table to Folder CSV table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Good evening!

We are currently having an issue with the below error being thrown when trying to refresh a dataset via the on-premises gateway. Refreshing direct through Power BI desktop does not provide any errors and seems to refresh fine.

```
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
"pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
"parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode",
"detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage",
"detail":{"type":1,"value":"The key didn't match any rows in the table."}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult",
"detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Key",
"detail":{"type":1,"value":"[entity = \"Forecast\"]"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason",
"detail":{"type":1,"value":"Expression.Error"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: FACT - Cost Forecast Tool.
Cluster URI: WABI-EUROPE-NORTH-B-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: f4b629a6-a9bc-4966-954c-ae37139737a4
Request ID: db16cb6d-a765-1e0e-f9f5-b8803c8baa6e
Time: 2020-11-25 17:20:30Z
```

From reading previous posts, I'm not sure any of the normal responses apply in this scenario, as they tend to relate to either pulling data from SQL Server, or Excel files (where the sheet name causes an issue).

The table throwing the error (FACT - Cost Forecast Tool) is made by appending two other tables - one comes from a Power BI dataflow (Forecast), and one from a folder import of CSV files (Forecast Tool Adjustments).

Publishing a model with just the two individual tables (Forecast and Forecast Tool Adjustments) works and refreshes fine.

The above error only occurs where a third table is added combining these two tables via a one liner in Power Query:

`= Table.Combine({#"Forecast Tool Adjustments", Forecast})`

Oddly the value being flagged in the error, "[entity = "Forecast"]", is one of the first steps in Power Query for the 'Forecast' table. So while that table refreshes fine if it's on it's own, it seems to throw an error when refreshed through the combined table?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide your powerquery code?

Comment: You need to share your entire M code (Advanced Editor) for us to understand how you've sourced the data.